# Kotlin error ResourcesNotFoundException on resources,getFont()

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating a pdf document in my Kotlin Android project, I am using `android.grapics.Paint` to add data to pdf file. I got `ResourcesNotFoundException` when I tried to change the font.
The thing is I am already using this same thing for timesnewroman font but when I added another font, it gives error.

My code which is working fine::

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        titlePaint.typeface = Typeface.create(resources.getFont(R.font.timesnewroman), Typeface.NORMAL)
    }
```

Code which gives error:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            titlePaint.typeface = Typeface.create(resources.getFont(R.font.arialth), Typeface.NORMAL)
        }
```

Fonts folder:
[image]

Please tell me if I am missing any step here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

> titlePaint.typeface = Typeface.create(
> ResourcesCompat.getFont(this.applicationContext, R.font.arialth),
> Typeface.NORMAL
> )

Comment: Hi, still getting the same error.